# How do I instrument methods that are loaded from a specific jar with javassist?

Tags: instrumentation, javassist

I have a sample jar that I am loading into the the class pool from disk.  From there I can easily get access to the methods inside of this class and instrument them as you can see I did with the JsEval method.

However, inside of the Helloworld sampleclass I would like to be able to instrument other library function calls.  In this example I am attempting to instrument the eval function from the nashorn scripting engine. However this does not work.  I am able to get access to the class (pool.get) just fine and am able to patch the methods for eval.  But when I run the SampleClass from cl.run() the methods execute like no code was inserted.  I suspect this is something to do with the class loader I am using to execute the Sampleclass but I am stuck.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

```java
public class maventest {

  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException, Throwable
  {
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    Loader cl = new Loader(pool);

    //pool.importPackage(Test.class.getPackage().getName());
    //Get the Jar from disk. This works and the method is instrumented.
    pool.insertClassPath(
      "Z:\\HelloWorld\\target\\HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
    );  
    pool.importPackage("com.mycompany.helloworld");
    //pool.appendClassPath();

    CtClass helloworld = pool.get("com.mycompany.helloworld.SampleClass");
    helloworld
      .getDeclaredMethod("JsEval")
      .insertBefore(
        "System.out.println(\"Calling JsEval from within helloworld\\n\");"
      );

    //This does not work.
    //Attempt to instrument the eval function that is called from inside of HelloWorld
    String classToLoad = "jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine";
    String constuctor_name = "eval";
    CtClass nash = pool.get(classToLoad);
    //Multiple eval calls.. Just instrument them all.
    CtMethod[] meths = nash.getDeclaredMethods("eval");
    for (CtMethod m : meths) {
      m.insertBefore(
        "System.out.println(\"Nashorn Scripting Engined eval called.\");"
      );
    }

    //Execute the hello world class with null args
    cl.run("com.mycompany.helloworld.SampleClass", null);
  }

}
```

Here is the sample code that calls the lib functions I wish to instrument.

```java
public class SampleClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NotFoundException {
    JsEval("var greeting='hello world'; print(greeting) + greeting");
  }

  private static void JsEval(String js) {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    try {
      Object result = engine.eval(js);
    }
    catch (ScriptException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(SampleClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the question is kind of old, but it is still unanswered and I was curious.

The reason this is not working is that `getDeclaredMethods("eval")` does not search for methods in superclasses, as is documented in the Javadoc. The method you are calling, i.e. the one taking the single `String` parameter is defined in the parent class `AbstractScriptEngine`, though, not in `NashornScriptEngine`. So either you have to change the target class to the class where the method is really defined or you search for methods via `getMethod(..)` or `getMethods()`, both of which also return inherited methods. Because `getMethods()` cannot take a method name parameter but returns all methods and you would have to filter by name again in your instrumentation loop, I suggest you single out the one method you really want to instrument by specifying its exact signature:

```java
String classToLoad = "jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine";
CtClass nash = pool.get(classToLoad);
CtMethod m = nash.getMethod(
  "eval",
  Descriptor.ofMethod(
    pool.get("java.lang.Object"),
    new CtClass[] { pool.get("java.lang.String") }
  )
);
m.insertBefore("System.out.println(\"Nashorn Scripting Engined eval called.\");");
```

Or if `Descriptor.ofMethod(..)` is too long-winded for you and you feel comfortable with the descriptor syntax:

```java
String classToLoad = "jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine";
CtClass nash = pool.get(classToLoad);
CtMethod m = nash.getMethod("eval", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
m.insertBefore("System.out.println(\"Nashorn Scripting Engined eval called.\");");
```

Now your console log output is as expected:

```
Calling JsEval from within helloworld

Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
hello world
```

---

**Update:** Oops, I missed the fact that you are trying to modify a bootstrap class or more generally a class which was already loaded. In that case the transformation has no effect, unless you use Java instrumentation API, i.e. use a `ClassFileTransformer` which you either integrate into a Java agent (use your favourite web search engine if you don't know what a Java agent is and how to build one) or attach dynamically. I use the tiny `byte-buddy-agent` library in order to hot-attach it to the running JVM here in this example, just so I can show you the effect.

A super-simplistic version which is not very generic but engineered to only look for the `eval(String)` method, looks like this:

```java
import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtMethod;
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine;
import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.lang.instrument.UnmodifiableClassException;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MavenTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws UnmodifiableClassException {
    Instrumentation instrumentation = ByteBuddyAgent.install();
    instrumentation.addTransformer(new ScriptEngineTransformer());

    Class<?> targetClass = NashornScriptEngine.class;
    // Go up the super class hierarchy, pretending we don't know the exact
    // super class class in which the target method is defined
    while (!targetClass.equals(Object.class)) {
      instrumentation.retransformClasses(targetClass);
      targetClass = targetClass.getSuperclass();
    }

    jsEval("var greeting='hello world'; print(greeting)");
  }

  private static void jsEval(String js) {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    try {
      engine.eval(js);
    }
    catch (ScriptException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(MavenTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }

  static class ScriptEngineTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {
    private static final ClassPool CLASS_POOL = ClassPool.getDefault();

    @Override
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
      CtClass targetClass;
      try {
        // Caveat: Do not just use 'classPool.get(className)' because we would miss previous transformations.
        // It is necessary to really parse 'classfileBuffer'.
        targetClass = CLASS_POOL.makeClass(new ByteArrayInputStream(classfileBuffer));
        CtMethod evalMethod = targetClass.getDeclaredMethod("eval", new CtClass[] { CLASS_POOL.get("java.lang.String") });
        targetClass.defrost();
        evalMethod.insertBefore("System.out.println(\"Scripting engine eval(String) called\");");
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
      }

      byte[] transformedBytecode;
      try {
        transformedBytecode = targetClass.toBytecode();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
      }

      return transformedBytecode;
    }
  }

}
```

You may have noticed that I renamed a few of your class and method names in order to make them comply to Java standards.

Now the console log is:

```
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Scripting engine eval(String) called
hello world
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is close to how I ended up getting it to work.  Sorry for the late reply and thanks for the help again!